# Dynamically setting variables within a function with exec()

Tags: python, variables, dynamic, exec

This is just a skeleton of what I'm trying to do, mostly it'll be used for taking a global variable on a function call to store to disk current operational state, but instead of a massive static block of code, I'm trying to use a function call to create needed storage state and set its contents, for the desired object/variable in active use.

```
colorlist = ["AliceBlue","#F0F8FF","AntiqueWhite","#FAEBD7","Aqua"]
tmpobj = None

def chgState(objname):
    global tmpobj
    exec(f"global {objname}")
    exec(f"tmpobj = {objname}")
    print(f"{objname} {type(**tmpobj**)}\n") #**'s only to show step point, they are not in the code
    print(f"{obj}")
    #file storage junk.. blah blah

chgState("colorlist")
```

I keep getting `tmpobj undefined`, but if I step through the code, **`tmpobj`** that's in the code will show the correct contents before erroring out.

Would be preferred to be able to utilize some of the globals but even in a local context would be nice.

I've even attempted using `__local[{objname}]` in the `exec` block but once again `tmpobj undefined`.

Comment: Sure seems like a dictionary would be a better choice than a bunch of global variable...but that's just me.

Comment: Instead of `exec()` you can use `globals()[objname]`

Comment: one of the objects i'm handling is a list of dictionaries, that's parsed over time.

i'd looked into storing the variable data as a include file, then editing the source .py to do an import, but that gets super messy and requires stops and re-starts. versus a file data read, also avoiding using databases as some of the data is just big blobs.

Comment: You really want to just pass in a dictionary and put the data in that.  `globals()` is just a dictionary that happens to also contain all the other variables that you declare in your code, so using `globals()` is just like using a regular dictionary except there are way more opportunities for confusion.

Answer (score 0):

[@Barmar's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71974597/dynamically-setting-variables-within-a-function-with-exec/71974727#comment127181008_71974597) nailed it:

```
colorlist = ["AliceBlue","#F0F8FF","AntiqueWhite","#FAEBD7","Aqua"]
tmpobj = None

def chgState(objname):
    global tmpobj
    exec(f"global {objname}")
    tmpobj = globals()[objname] # Magic here - thanks again
    print(f"{objname} {type(tmpobj)}\n")
    print(f"{tmpobj}")
    #file storage junk.. blah blah

chgState("colorlist")
```

Comment: New issue: i can parse the data to file including the variable name and setting the value as an exec() ready command to read back, it'll assign the value, but it doesn't  create a list, it makes a string "list"

Comment: got around this to some degree, i write what i want as assignments to an external file and the use a function call to import the file and in turn get the dynamic variable assignments with it, unfortunately the file name has to be static, and has to be present when starting the code.